# JQuery Draggable Helper Clone Position Offset from Cursor After Scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Currently I am using JQuery 2.0.3 and JQuery UI 1.10.4. I am attempting to use the Draggable API. My list of draggable items extends past the length of the page. When attempting to drag an item after scrolling, the item is no longer at the cursor. It shows up below the cursor. Its distance away from the cursor increases with how far down I've scrolled.

This issue occurs in both Chrome and Firefox, but is functions properlt in Safari. I have removed all CSS and left just the Draggable code intact and the issue persists. Any help in resolving this issue is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if any additional details are needed. Below are the HTML and JS segments:

HTML (generated from PHP):

```
echo '<div id="container">';
echo '<div id="category">';
    echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            echo '<li class="item">', $item['itemName'], '</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
```

echo '';

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#category li').draggable({
        appendTo: 'body',
        helper: 'clone',
        connectToSortable: '#cart ul'
    });
 });
```

Thank you in advance for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/h3n3P/1/). I used the google CDN first and was able to see the issue.  But then I updated the reference to [Jquery UI JS](http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js) and [JQuery UI CSS](http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css).  You don't need to add css reference, but try using js reference and see if it works for you.

Code is still the same:

```
$(function() {
    $('#category li').draggable({
        appendTo: 'body',
        helper: 'clone',
        connectToSortable: '#cart ul'
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this. The jsFiddle seems to be working exactly as I was looking for. I will try the modified JS file with my code to see if it works. Out of curiosity, what did you modify in the JS file to correct the behavior? Thank you again.

Comment: I did not modify anything in the js file.  I suppose it is a different version from what you have...

Comment: Thank you very much. I see now. The version I was using was the production version 1.10. The version you were referencing is the preproduction version 1.11. I updated the reference in my files and the items are behaving as desired. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, and if you look at the link http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9315 you will see that this was an issue in 1.10.3, which was fixed in later versions.  I am glad this was helpful!

Comment: Thank you for the ticket number. The specific version I was using when I was experiencing the error was v1.10.4. So far the pre-production v1.11.0 is working well.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. After hours of hair pulling I can finally rest in peace now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. I resolve it when I remove appendTo:body .

try this code

```
    $('#category li').draggable({
      helper: 'clone',
      connectToSortable: '#cart ul'
    });
```